# SQL Get row number from the main table

Tags: sql, oracle

Using SQL, how can I get the actual row number of the data from the Master table, when I combined two tables (Master-table and Table-2). Please see illustration below:

Table-1 (Master Table)

```
    Name       Age
   ---------- ------     
1   Ruth     | 45
2   Jennifer | 52
3   Isabel   | 29
4   Jo       | 59
5   Dan      | 35
6   Lem      | 26
```

Table-2

```
    Name       Color
   ---------- ------       
1   Ruth     | Blue
2   Jennifer | Blue
3   Isabel   | Red
4   Jo       | Blue
5   Dan      | Red
6   Lem      | Blue
```

The result I want to get: (1) get records where color is blue, (2) new column (Row_Number from Table-1):

```
    Name       Age    Color    Row_Number
   ---------- ------ -------- ------------
1   Ruth     | 45   | Blue   | 1
2   Jennifer | 52   | Blue   | 2
3   Jo       | 59   | Blue   | 4
4   Lem      | 26   | Blue   | 6
```

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no "row number" in a table (although Oracle does have a `rowid`).  Is there a column that specifies the ordering?

Comment: If you are storing any kind of sequence in the table, then you could simply join the tables and get the desired sequence number. However, there is no specific order of rows in a table. While you fetch, you must explicitly mention ORDER BY to sort the rows in your desired order. Else, Oracle would return you a random set of rows.

Comment: is there a date column  with timestamp in your table and what you mean by rownumber is the order the data was inserted ????

Comment: you should use primary keys in your tables

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your issue :

```
with all_users as 
(
   select *, row_number over(order by name/*order by whatever you want*/) as seq
   from table1
) select *, all_users.seq
  from table2
  join all_users using(name);
```

You could also use a subquery, but I prefer `with` when using Oracle.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer but, I do not have stored sequence number in any of the table. Can you think of way to get the line number from table-1?

Comment: @MarvinWong You don't need any sequence with the method I posted, simply order by whatever you want and the rownumber will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_nummber()`, but you need to specify your sorting condition

```
select t.name,t.age,tbl.color,tbl.rn as rownumber 
from table2 t
join (select name,color,row_nummber() over (order by name) as rn from table1) tbl
on t.name=tbl.name
```

**EDIT:** and if you you don't have any sort condition (as mentioned in comment) then you can simply use `rownum` without specifying sort condition:

```
select t.name,t.age,tbl.color,tbl.rn as rownumber 
from table2 t
join (select name,color,rownum as rn from table1) tbl
on t.name=tbl.name
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer but, I do not have stored sequence number in any of the table. Can you think of way to get the line number from table-1?